# Insert em vários campos de input em tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, javascript, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho os campos de data, CNPJ, latitude, longitude, site, facebook, na mesma tela, só que são de 3 tabelas diferentes, como faço para dar o `insert` nelas a partir do mesmo botão?? Que uso para salvar as informações mas nem todos os campos são obrigatórios.

Comment: Em seu script PHP tem que fazer 3 queries de insert para gravar os dados. Posta seu código PHP e a estrutura de suas 3 tabelas para que possamos ajudar melhor.

Comment: A questão está um pouco incompleta. De que botão você está falando? **`"Insert"`** aonde? SQL? Está usando PDO, mysqli ou mysql? E qual é sua dúvida em relação à inserir algo em uma tabela do banco de dados, então?

Answer (score 1):

Eu entendi que todos os campos estão num único FORM, e que vc manda todos eles na mesma requisição para tratamento/gravação em tabelas diferentes. Vc pode separar os dados passados pelo formulário e criar consultas SQL independentes para gravá-los. Supondo que o `script` recebe os dados via `$_POST`:

```
´foreach($_POST as $var => $value){
  if($var == 'cnpj'){
   $query = "INSERT INTO table_name1($var) VALUES ($value); ";
  }
  if($var == 'latitude'){
   $query = $query . "INSERT INTO table_name2($var) VALUES ($value); ";
  }}
  echo $query;´
```

A resposta deve ser essa aqui:

```
´INSERT INTO table_name1(cnpj) VALUES (000000000000); 
 INSERT INTO table_name2(latitude) VALUES (1245165421341);´
```

No fim, basta executar a `$query` formada.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Você pode usar arrays de input no html separando por cada tabela que deseja inserir os dados, por exemplo:

```
    <form action="inputArray.php" method="post">

        <label>tbl1 Nome</label>                
        <input type="text" name="tbl1[nome]"/><br/>
        <label>tbl1 Sobrenome</label>
        <input type="text" name="tbl1[sobrenome]"/><br/>
        <label>tbl1 Idade</label>
        <input type="text" name="tbl1[idade]"/><br/><br/>

        <label>tbl2 Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="tbl2[nome]"/><br/>
        <label>tbl2 Sobrenome</label>
        <input type="text" name="tbl2[sobrenome]"/><br/>
        <label>tbl2 Idade</label>
        <input type="text" name="tbl2[idade]"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    </form>
```

Se na pagina de destino você der um `print_r($_POST)`, vai ter o seguinte resultado:

```
Array ( 
[tbl1] => Array ( [nome] => [sobrenome] => [idade] => )
[tbl2] => Array ( [nome] => [sobrenome] => [idade] => ) 
)
```

onde `tbl1` e `tbl2` sao as suas tabelas, depois disso é so fazer os inserts

```
$tbl1 = $_POST['tbl1'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (nome, sobrenome, idade) VALUES($tbl1['nome'], $tbl1['sobrenome'], $tbl1['idade'])";`
```

e ai é só repetir para as demais tabelas.

Espero ter ajudado.
Estou a disposição para qualquer dúvida.
Abraço.